# If value in range(x,y) function c#

Tags: c#, range

Does c# have a function that returns a boolean for expression : `if(value.inRange(-1.0,1.0)){}`?

Comment: Inclusive or exclusive? What about `if (value >= 1.0 && value <= 1.0)`?

Comment: What types should this function operate on? Integral? Float? Any class?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: is it good to make your own venchile, instead of using standard way? And then each other should check "what does this function do"

Comment: I have many arguments to check and thinked that c# has an fuction for it. All values of type float.

Comment: Why turn it to a method in the first place? It makes the code harder to read than simply writing out the expression, as @FrédéricHamidi did. This is especially bad if an ambiguous method name such as `InRange` is used.

Comment: possibly porting from Delphi code that has a Math.InRange function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Description

I suggest you use a extension method.

> **Extension methods** enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

You can create this extension method in a generic way (thx to digEmAll and CodeInChaos, who suggest that). Then you can use that on every object that implements `IComparable`.

#### Solution

```
public static class IComparableExtension
{
    public static bool InRange<T>(this T value, T from, T to) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return value.CompareTo(from) >= 1 && value.CompareTo(to) <= -1;
    }
}
```

then you do this

```
double t = 0.5;
bool isInRange = t.InRange(-1.0, 1.0);
```

### Update for perfectionists

After an extensive discussion with @CodeInChaos who said

> I'd probably go with IsInOpenInterval as suggested in an earlier comment. But I'm not sure if programmers without a maths background will understand that terminology.

You can name the function `IsInOpenInterval` too.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)
- [MSDN - IComparable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx)

Comment: At least keep to .NET naming conventions and name it `InRange`.

Comment: Okey. Thanks, this is suitable for me.

Comment: @wsevendays consider to accept if this was the right answer for you. have a nice day

Comment: You could make this even more generic, changing `double` into `IComparable<T>` then using `CompareTo` instead of `<` `>`

Comment: In the current version the name is ambiguous. It's not clear if you're talking about an open or a closed interval. I'd rename it to `InOpenInterval`

Comment: Great with the new change you're now boxing the values, and you lost all type safety. I think what @digEmAll meant was to use the signature `bool InRange<T>(T value, T from, T to) where T:IComperable<T>`.

Comment: Let us talk about it @CodeInChaos. I don't think so, because i use the extension method approach `this IComparable value` makes sure that the type is safe. In case of using a simple method `bool InRange<T>(T value, T from, T to) where T:IComperable<T>` would be right. Greets to munich, from regensburg (ratisbona) ;)

Comment: Aaah, to tired ;) I know understand what you mean. I change the answer and merge our two approaches.

Comment: @dknaack: my suggestion was exaclty what @CodeInChaos said. And, BTW you shouldn't use `== 1` and `== -1` because `CompareTo` does not guarantee to return those numbers, but a number `less than 0`, `equal to 0` or `greater than 0`. [--> LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx)

Comment: Thank you guys, good stuff. Are you agree with answer or did you see anything to improve ?

Comment: There's always room for improvements... ;) For example you could add a boolean to include/exclude extremes, but that's beyond the OP request. So basically it's ok to me.

Comment: I'd still change the method name to make it clear that you're talking about an open, and not a closed interval. I probably wouldn't make it an extension method either, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @CodeInChaos something like `IsBetween` ?

Comment: Not sure if the word "between" implies anything about the boundary cases. I'd put in one of the words "open", "exclusive" or "strictly".

Comment: @CodeInChaos suggest a method name please.

Comment: I'd probably go with `IsInOpenInterval` as suggested in an earlier comment. But I'm not sure if programmers without a maths background will understand that terminology.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't duplicate the method with different names. That's just confusing.

Comment: @CodeInChaos ok, thats it i think. My answer is updated again.

Comment: Do you think we should delete our comments to not confuse the users or should not delete to make it possible to understand the answer better ?

Comment: Keep the comments.  See https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/when-should-comments-be-deleted for further discussion on such a topic.  The comments to relate directly to the refined answer and they are all 'nice'!

Comment: Could I suggest you change 'for perfectionists' to 'Better mathematical terminology'

Comment: current code excludes lower and upper range boundaries: to make this inclusive:   return value.CompareTo(lbound) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(ubound) <= 0;

Answer (score 4):

Use `Math.Abs(value) <= 1.0` for example

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear, but may be inverse:

`Enumerable. Range(-1, 2).Any(x=>x==value)`.

By the way didn't compile this, writing from mobile.

**edit**

here I'm using [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

**edit1**

if we are talking about `floating point` numbers, it's enough to create an `extension method` which generates the sequence of numbers by specifying `start number` and `offset step` and after execute `Any<T>` on resulting collection, like in aswer provided.

Comment: This is only for int, but I need float.

Comment: @wsevendsys: so what is the number sequence in case of `(-1.0, 1.0)`?

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. He wants to test if a floating point number is in an interval. i.e. something like `lower<=value<=upper`. He doesn't want to create a sequence.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: but why in the comment to answer of jdehaan he wrote: "How to pass many arguments?".. Bah.. peace.

Comment: I think he wants to do the test on many values, but it's not really clear what he wants.

Comment: @Tigran, this is values from accelerometer.